# Kotlin - idiomatic way to create a Fragment newInstance pattern

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

The best practice on Android for creating a `Fragment` is to use a static factory method and pass arguments in a `Bundle` via `setArguments()`.

In Java, this is done something like:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    static MyFragment newInstance(int foo) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("foo", foo);
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

In Kotlin this converts to:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
       fun newInstance(foo: Int): MyFragment {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("foo", foo)
            val fragment = MyFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sense to support interop with Java so it can still be called via `MyFragment.newInstance(...)`, but is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin if we don't need to worry about Java interop?

Answer (score 83):

I like to do it this way:

```
companion object {
    private const val MY_BOOLEAN = "my_boolean"
    private const val MY_INT = "my_int"

    fun newInstance(aBoolean: Boolean, anInt: Int) = MyFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle(2).apply {
            putBoolean(MY_BOOLEAN, aBoolean)
            putInt(MY_INT, anInt)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: with KotlinX extensions, you can also do this

```
companion object {
    private const val MY_BOOLEAN = "my_boolean"
    private const val MY_INT = "my_int"

    fun newInstance(aBoolean: Boolean, anInt: Int) = MyFragment().apply {
        arguments = bundleOf(
            MY_BOOLEAN to aBoolean,
            MY_INT to anInt)
    }
}
```

Comment: i there any way to make the primary constructor of the fragment private in order to avoid instancing without using newInstance method?

Comment: The constructor must be public and have no arguments, as the framework will use reflection to find that constructor and instantiate the fragment when recreating it (rotation, resuming from background, ...).

Comment: Is it best practice to use the `@JvmStatic` annotation? `@JvmStatic fun newInstance(bundle: Bundle) = SomeFragment().apply { arguments = bundle  }`

Answer (score 16):

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment>
    newFragmentInstance(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>) =
    T::class.java.newInstance().apply {
        arguments = bundleOf(*params)
    }`
```

So it is used like that:

```
val fragment = newFragmentInstance<YourFragment>("key" to value)
```

[Credit](https://gist.github.com/rakshakhegde/eea58a24994ac8ce27842febcc1f2ab0)

`bundleOf()` can be taken from [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/static/commons/src/ContextUtils.kt)

Comment: Fancy, but it doesn't actually solve the problem that the whole `static newInstance(..)` charade is set out to solve; namely to encode the ***required*** arguments of the fragment in a static factory method. Now you'll have to write `"key"` in multiple places, and possibly forget it at some point, fail to modify it at some point, etc. so this means you could use your helper to implement it like, `companion object { fun newInstance(name: String) = newFragmentInstance<MyFragment>("name" to name)`

Answer (score 12):

Late to the party, but I believe Idiomatically it should be something like this:

```
private const val FOO = "foo"
private const val BAR = "bar"

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(foo: Int, bar: String) = MyFragment().withArgs {
            putInt(FOO, foo)
            putString(BAR, bar)
        }
    }
}
```

With an extension like this:

```
inline fun <T : Fragment> T.withArgs(argsBuilder: Bundle.() -> Unit): T =
    this.apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply(argsBuilder)
    }
```

or

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(foo: Int, bar: String) = MyFragment().apply {
        arguments = bundleOf(
            FOO to foo,
            BAR to bar
        )
    }
 }
```

The key being that the private constants should not be part of the companion object.

Comment: "The key being that the private constants should not be part of the companion object." Where do I learn more about this?

Comment: This has a great summary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969319/kotlin-difference-between-constant-in-companion-object-and-top-level

Answer (score 12):

```
companion object {
  private const val NOTE_ID = "NOTE_ID"
  fun newInstance(noteId: Int?) = AddNoteFragment().apply {
  arguments =
      Bundle().apply { putInt(NOTE_ID, noteId ?: Int.MIN_VALUE) }
  }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
  arguments?.let {
    noteId = it.getInt(NOTE_ID)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this I [found here](https://gist.github.com/azjkjensen/cf094c79726bab08b68f01dcc2e82a71#file-myfragment-kt)

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(){
  companion object{
    private val ARG_CAUGHT = "myFragment_caught"

    fun newInstance(caught: Pokemon):MyFragment{
      val args: Bundle = Bundle()
      args.putSerializable(ARG_CAUGHT, caught)
      val fragment = MyFragment()
      fragment.arguments = args
      return fragment
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More elegant way in my opinion

```
open class Instance<T : Fragment> {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun newInstance(vararg args: Pair<String, Any?>): T {
        val cls = Class.forName(javaClass.name.substringBefore("$"))
        return (cls.newInstance() as T).apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(*args)
        }
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object : Instance<MyFragment>()
}
```

Keep in mind to add proguard rule to save constructor

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
   <init>(...);
}
```

Or without reflection and proguard

```
open class Instance<T : Fragment>(private val cls: Class<T>) {

    fun newInstance(vararg args: Pair<String, Any?>): T {
        return cls.newInstance().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(*args)
        }
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object : Instance<MyFragment>(MyFragment::class.java)
}
```

Example of usage

```
val myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance("foo" to "bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin package-level function**

What about about that kotlin says to use package level function instead of “static” method

*MyFragment.kt*

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    .....

}

fun MyFragmentNewInstance(): MyFragment {
    return MyFragment()
}
```

MyActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer) == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, MyFragmentNewInstance())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: But is this really an improvement compared to `MyFragment.newInstance()` in `MyFragment`'s `companion object`?

Comment: I really don´t know if there is an improvement, It's just doing the code more "Kotlin way"

Comment: @IrvingLóp That's, not a good idea. This will create two instances of MyFragment.

Comment: @DawidHyży Why a package level function will create two instances? I really don't see how.