# Sending Data from Activity to Fragment Using Arguments (Kotlin/Android)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, race-condition

I am trying to send data from an Activity to it's child fragment. I have one activity that first loads all the fragments like this:

```
    view_pager.adapter = TabsAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
```

`TabsAdapter` here is just an if condition for a tab carousel that supports swiping and clicking tab headers to change tabs.

After I load the tabs I call a Fuel http request to get weather data from https://openweathermap.org, a very simple API. I successfully retrieve my local weather and can log the output to the console. Where I am stuck is sending the data to the Fragment.

There are a lot of stackoverflow answers to this question. My issue is that I need to do two things:

1) send the data to the fragment, preferably using an argument as this looks simplest 
and

2) setting some textViews in my fragment to be the value of the weather (display "It's sunny!")

Here is how I am attempting to solve the problem so far:

In my activity, after the data comes back from the http request, I put the data in a bundle and send the bundle to a method inside my fragment class:

```
 println("success from json request to weatherAPI")
 val weatherArray = result.get().obj().getJSONArray("weather").get(0) as JSONObject
 println("value of main in weatherArray:" + weatherArray["main"])
 println("value of description in weatherArray:" + weatherArray["description"])
 println("value of icon in weatherArray: " + weatherArray["icon"])

 val args = Bundle()
 args.putString("weatherurl",  "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+weatherArray["icon"]+".png")
 args.putString("weatherdescription", weatherArray["description"].toString())
 args.putString("weathermain", weatherArray["main"].toString())

 val homeFrag = HomeFragment()
 homeFrag.getWeather(args)
```

Here is the fragment I am working with. So in `onCreateView` I set the `weathermainView` and `weatherdescriptionView` to items that I have in the layout for the fragment. I have to do this in `onCreateView` because this is the only place where `view` is available. I have these as public variables because I need them accessible in my `getWeather` function.

My `getWeather` function tries to take the bundle arguments and set them equal to the textViews, **however** no matter what I do `weathermainView` and `weatherdescriptionView` text values are null, and they do not show in my page in the emulator. I had originally thought that I was experiencing a race condition between creating the tab and getting the data in the activity, so I put in a timeout. However, this does not solve the problem either.

Here is the fragment code:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
     var weathermainView: TextView?=null
     var weatherdescriptionView:  TextView?=null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        weathermainView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textWeatherMain)
        weatherdescriptionView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textWeatherDescription)
        println("!!!after setting weathermainView in onCreateView!!!")
        println("value of weathermainView " + weathermainView?.text.toString())

        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    fun getWeather(args: Bundle){
        val weatherMain = args.getString("weathermain")
        val weatherDescription = args.getString("weatherdescription")
        val timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(timerTask {
            println("value of weathermainView BEFORE SETTING" + weathermainView?.text.toString())
            println("value of weatherdescriptionView BEFORE SETTING" + weatherdescriptionView?.text.toString())
            weathermainView?.text =  args.getString("weathermain")
            weatherdescriptionView?.text = args.getString("weatherdescription")
            println("value of weathermainView " + weathermainView?.text.toString())
            println("value of weatherdescriptionView " + weatherdescriptionView?.text.toString())
        }, 10000)

        println("Value of weatherMain: " + weatherMain)
        println("Value of weatherDescription: " + weatherDescription)

    }
}
```

Here is the command line output I'm seeing:

```
I/System.out: !!!after setting weathermainView in onCreateView!!!
I/System.out: value of weathermainView hello there home fragment
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9ab28d60: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9ab28d60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x99bf5790)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9ab28d60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x99bf5790)
I/System.out: success from json request to weatherAPI
I/System.out: value of main in weatherArray:Rain
I/System.out: value of description in weatherArray:light rain
I/System.out: value of icon in weatherArray: 10d
I/System.out: Value of weatherMain: Rain
I/System.out: Value of weatherDescription: light rain
I/System.out: value of weathermainView BEFORE SETTING: null
I/System.out: value of weatherdescriptionView BEFORE SETTING: null
I/System.out: value of weathermainView null
I/System.out: value of weatherdescriptionView null
```

Note: `!!!after setting weathermainView in onCreateView!!!` is the first output, so the tabs must be instantiated before the response comes back from the http request and the `getWeather` call is made. **And** both setting the weather variables in the activity and `onCreateView` of fragment works. **But**

```
I/System.out: value of weathermainView BEFORE SETTING: null
I/System.out: value of weatherdescriptionView BEFORE SETTING: null
I/System.out: value of weathermainView null
I/System.out: value of weatherdescriptionView null
```

**So why are these null?**

There's no race condition, I can set in `onCreatView` successfully. I even put in a timeout. I'm very confused, any hints would help.

EDIT:

Here is my TabsAdapter:

```
class TabsAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {
    // Title for tabs
    private val fragmentTitles = arrayOf("Home", "Music", "Map")
    // Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> HomeFragment()
            1 -> MusicFragment()
            2 -> MapFragment()
            else -> HomeFragment()
        }
    }
    // Return the number of views/fragments available.
    override fun getCount(): Int = 3 // in our case 3 fragments
    // Return title based on position
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return fragmentTitles[position]
    }
}
```

Comment: write the bundle related codes in `onActivityCreated` or `onViewCreated` you may not get the error.. update if it works..

Comment: Hmmm....Not sure that I know how. I try and pass arguments from activity like this: ` homeFrag.arguments.putString(someweatherstring)`. In `onViewCreated` I have `val weatherurl = arguments.getString("weatherurl")` but this gives the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`. What is `arguments` supposed to be the modifier of in the fragment?

Comment: first you need to get the arguments like `getArguments()`

Comment: Remember, this is in Kotlin, so get/setArguments() is now arguments. It has a slightly different syntax.

Comment: I have the similar issue. Have you solved your? Can you please share what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The following line in your code gives you a new instance of HomeFragment:

```
val homeFrag = HomeFragment()
```

This instance is not attached to the `Activity` so there's no need to execute  `onCreateView()` . Because of this, the `TextView`s are all `null`.

You want to display the new data in the `Fragment` which is already attached to the `TabLayout`. So you need to keep a handle to it in some variable - let's call it  *homeFragment* - and write

```
homeFragment.getWeather(args);
```

Looking at your `TabsAdapter` implementation, I think it's also a good idea to pass *args* to the Adapter so the Adapter in turn can pass the data to the `HomeFragment` for the next time it is to be displayed. To achieve this, `HomeFragment` needs a static `instance()` method which will take a Bundle parameter and return a `HomeFragment` instance. Then you can use this method instead of the Constructor.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104345/kotlin-idiomatic-way-to-create-a-fragment-newinstance-pattern) shows how to do it in Kotlin.

Comment: This is a very good point. I've posted my TabsAdapter. Perhaps I should write a function in there to grab the Fragment class somehow....Not sure though. I have to admit I'm a little bit lost, I haven't seen many SO posts that go into this much depth on how to handle Fragments in a TabAdapter.

Comment: @Peter Weyand - like my edited answer says: instead of HomeFragment() you use HomeFragment.instance(args) I must admit though that this is plain old Java, not sure how to say it in Kotlin. But I'll try to find out and be back

Comment: @Peter Weyand - found something on Stack Overflow, I hope it's useful

Comment: I appreciate the insight. Still having trouble - the issue I have now is an async one. So if I call `TabsAdapter.newInstanceHome("weatherurl",  "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+weatherArray["icon"]+".png")` from within my rest call, and in `onCreateView` I have `val bdl: Bundle = arguments` arguments will be null and throw an error. Why?  Because `onCreateView` fires before the rest call finishes. I can do other lifecycle methods within the Fragments, but then I'm just hoping that the Fragment satisfies the race condition.

Comment: @Peter Weyand - wouldn't it be better to show old data or "loading..." while doing the refresh and, as soon as you have new data, publish them? Your TabsAdapter could have a method refresh(position: Int, args:  Bundle). Then either HomeFragment is on display and you can simply call getWeather() or it isn't and then next time it should be shown you use args with the instance() method

Comment: I agree that that would be better, but I don't think that I'm there yet. This is what I'm stuck on, following the link you edited at the bottom of your post. https://gist.github.com/patientplatypus/99209a72f80607cd0c6ab672c7ac3a55. Essentially, I don't have a lifecycle method for when a fragment is shown in a tab viewer and so I can't successfully push data to the fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165515/discussion-between-peter-weyand-and-0x0nosugar).