# Kotlin - Inheritance in Object expression

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to inherit the Object A from Object B, were both the objects consist of constants only.

Example

```
 Object A {
  const val a1 = "some_data_1"
  const val a2 = "some_data_2"
 }

 Object B : A {
  const val b1 = "some_data_3"
 }
```

is it feasible to achieve this in kotlin ?

Comment: Whats your usecase? Why do you habe to write `B.a1` ? Why not just `A.a1` ?

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin is an object-oriented programming (OOP) language. We can inherit object **A** from object **B** for that we have to to allow class "A" to be inherited, for that we need to attach the **open** modifier before the class to make it non-final.

For the **const** we have to use companion object, which is an object that is common to all instances of that class.

```
open class A {
     companion object {
        const val a1 = "some_data_1"
        const val a2 = "some_data_2"
     }
 }

class B : A() {
    companion object {
        const val b1 = "some_data_3"
    }
    val a_1 = a1
    val a_2 = a2
}
```

[Check this link to understand inheritance](https://www.journaldev.com/19705/kotlin-inheritance)

[Check this link to understand Companion Object](https://antonioleiva.com/objects-kotlin/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 open class A {
    companion object {
        const val a1 = "some_data_1"
        const val a2 = "some_data_2"
    }
}

class B : A() {
    companion object {
        const val b1 = "some_data_3"
    }
    val a_1 = a1
    val a_2 = a2
}
```

Comment: This creates an unneccessary class though.

Answer (score 0):

for a class to be inherited in Kotlin it should be `open` for example `open class A {}`
for class B to extends class A should add the `class B : A()`
for constants should be inside a `companion object {}`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably dive a bit deeper. 
[Object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) in your example is an `Object Declaration`.
You should have a look at [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions-and-declarations) doc describing Object Declarations and Object Expressions.

The question is - **Why would you need to have one class only with constants extend another(also containing only const vals)?**
Object Declarations are Kotlin built in [Singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and BTW are thread safe.
Example :

```
object DeviceProvider {


    private val _devices = ArrayList<Device>()

    fun getDevices() = _devices as List<Device>

    fun registerDevice(device: Device) {
        _devices.find { it == device } ?: _devices.add(device)
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
fun addDevice(){
    ServiceProvider.registerDevice(Device("1234"))
}
```

`Object declarations` are allowed to extend open classes and interfaces - so you can define a behavior or even a state via inheritance. As usual you can have a look at [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/inheritance.html) about inheritance, those are exhaustive and nice read.
Still if we are talking about common approaches defining const values - then separate file is the best solution, if of course that value should be bound to any specific class. Here is a nice point of view(thanks [Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977253/3874721)) :

> In Java you're forced to put all static field and method declarations
>   in a class and often you even have to create a class just for that
>   purpose. Coming to Kotlin, many users look for the equivalent facility
>   out of habit and end up overusing companion objects.
>
> Kotlin completely decouples the notions of a file and a class. You can
>   declare any number of public classes is the same file. You can also
>   declare private top-level functions and variables and they'll be
>   accessible only to the classes within the same file. This is a great
>   way to organize closely associated code and data.