# What is the correct way to set a TAG constant for debugging in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, scope, constants

Here are a couple of functionally similar code blocks...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object{
        const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Called")
  }
...
}
```

and

```
const val TAG = "MainActivity"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Called")
  }
...
}
```

Should the `const val TAG = "MainActivity"` be in a companion object, or top level? Would top level become an issue with namespaces, like other classes declaring top level `const val TAG = "OtherClass"`?

Comment: Why not put it in the class, but not in a companion object?

Comment: Because that generates this error: `Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects`

Comment: I've marked my own question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969319/kotlin-difference-between-constant-in-companion-object-and-top-level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: Difference between constant in companion object and top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969319/kotlin-difference-between-constant-in-companion-object-and-top-level)