# How to get data from companion object

Tags: kotlin, android-fragmentactivity, android-tablayout

I'm trying to make a tablayout with dynamic data, and I'm having trouble to get data from the companion object

```
package br.com.mirabilis.tab

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_one.*

class FragmentGeneric : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? =
        inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        tvIsi.setText(data) //not resolve data
    }


    companion object {
        fun newInstance(data : String): FragmentGeneric = FragmentGeneric()
    }
}
```

Thank you for anyone who wants to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to send arguments to fragment

```
companion object {
fun newInstance(data: String): MyFragment {
    val f = MyFragment ()
    // Pass index input as an argument.
    val args = Bundle()
    args.putString("data", data)
    f.setArguments(args)
    return f
  }
}
```

And get arguments like this

```
val args = arguments
val index = args.getString("data", "")
```

for more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104345/kotlin-idiomatic-way-to-create-a-fragment-newinstance-pattern)

Comment: thank you very much for your help. of course I will help others, but I am a beginner. I also wrote a blog about Kotlin that I just learned to help others

Comment: that's great thing go forward